# Arrayformula not working properly with Textjoin

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Here is the screenshot of the expected output and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGxWU.jpg)

I had to drag to bottom right thing down for the formula to carry over below (to produce expected output), but that doesn't have to happen with arrayformula right?

I tried removing arrayformula and only using textjoin, but all the names were in that cell...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF($D$2:$D$21=F2, $E$2:$E$21, "")))
```

thank you all in advance!

Comment: Textjoin can't be iterated over an array. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can work out an alternative approach.

Comment: how do i share my sheet

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/sharing-options-for-google-spreadsheets-3124090

Comment: or: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean, you always have to fill down formula to get result because join or textjoin does not return an array, your formula might be shorter like this:

```
= JOIN(",",FILTER($E$2:$E$21,$D$2:$D$21=F2))
```